# What is a raspberry pi useful for?

Tags: pi-2

Now I love doing a lot of reading and watch video on computer,science and electronics and next to the arduino I also heard of something called raspberry pi in most or my cse research I now it is a mini diy project computer and I also now you can make super cluster out of it and run server so is the raspberry pi a good tool for someone who loves to do research and watch video on computer,science and electronics like me?

Ps CSE means Computer Science Electronics.

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/

Comment: Welcome to the Pi Exchange. Please ask one specific question to allow for  good answers to be provided. You question is very broad, with sub questions and unclear comments. Also, please use grammar like you would be expected to be used at University on any written research paper. This question may get closed. Please do research on this site or anywhere else and we invite you to ask a more specific question soon.

Answer (score 3):

It's basically all you want it to be. Except a Netflix-box. Forget about netflix.

With enough time you could make it do almost anything. Within certain bounds tho, you won't break the pi-digit record on it. For basic DIY projects it's the perfect solution. It has more juice than the arduino and you have a full OS on it.

You can use it for programming, webserver, mediaserver, upgrade a tv to a smart tv, webbrowsing, carputer (computer in your car), electronics (you have the GPIO),.. The possibilities are endless.

Just buy one, you won't be disappointed. And if you are, it's only 40$/€/[insert currency], it's not the end of the world..

Comment: You can get a Pi Zero for 4USD or maybe 10USD with a kit. This answer does provide some insight but really lacks allot to be desired, due to the open ended question.